# Commit transactions if no error,rollback if error occured in Oracle SQL* plus

Tags: sql, oracle, commit, oracle-sqldeveloper

Following is small block of code i use to deploy the SQL scripts in my databases. I'm just wondering if i can automate this task of commit or rollback based in the result.

```
disc
connect username/password@database
spool D:\Deployments\path\to\logfile\logfile.log
@D:\Deployments\path\to\script\sqlquery_script.sql
```

If the sql script is ran successfully with out any errors means I want the system to Commit it automatically and in case any error is occcured all teh transactions should be rollbacked (Note that my sql script has many update statements)

When I use `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.CODE ROLLBACK;` the SQL* plus window is closed without showing any error.

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say what your script is.  How about putting it inside a PL/SQL anonymous block?

```
BEGIN
    ... updates here ...

    COMMIT; 
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE; 
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks @eaolson. it works fine! As you asked, my script will contain Update and Insert. for example, I may have 10-15 udpate queries and same amont of insert queries in same script file. Now I need to spool the result of each line of my script. is it possible?

Comment: DML inside a PL/SQL block does not cause the "x rows updated" type messages to be displayed. Instead, you can create your own messages and use dbms_output.put_line.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can give call to a procedure or in the Sql script you give call to procedure

exec procedureName(parameter1,parameter2);

Keep this statement in your sql file

and in case of exception keep this statement along with the above statement

EXCEPTION
      WHEN x_Error THEN
      ROLLBACK ;